# group ID hidden after vanity url established

Tags: facebook, facebook-group

I am trying to develop an app and use the group ID as the base but my group ID is hidden now that I have establish as vanity URL on FB. How do I see the group ID again?

Answer (score -1):

You can find it with http://wallflux.com/facebook_id/